# Access VBA TransferSpreadsheet data not exported with no error

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an Access application that uses VBA to export data to an Excel .xlsm file.

My line of code is

```
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "qry_ALL_Issue", fName, False, "IData"
```

Then my code goes on to open the Excel application and run the macro and that is what generates a report for the users.

My issue is this works on my computer but does not work for the other person. My error trap is never triggered so I am not getting an error in Access. The error trap in Excel triggers when it can't find the "IData" tab. I don't have an error code to work with so it is kind of hard to figure out what is going on.

I am using Office 2010 and the other person is using 2007. I tried to have them open the Excel file, modify it and save it - there was no change. I had them create a new blank file and this new file Access did export to. That means the issue is the Excel file obviously. So the question is why can I export to the .xlsm file and the other person can't? Put another way, what could be wrong with that file that he can't export to but I can?

Comment: I had the person who was having the issue create an excel doc on their machine and email it to me. I then copied all of the sheets and the macro to this new workbook. This new workbook they can export to. Nothing seems to be different between them so I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

As copied directly from *MSDN* concerning the range argument

*A string expression that's a valid range of cells or the name of a range in the spreadsheet. This argument applies only to importing. Leave this argument blank to import the entire spreadsheet. When you export to a spreadsheet, you must leave this argument blank. If you enter a range, the export will fail.*

When exporting, you must omit the `Range` argument. Maybe this will have something to do with it?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: However this works while exporting to a new Excel document for the other person and has been working on my PC for a while. So I have a feeling that this is not the issue however I will try to modify my code to see if there is any change.